# Fixing hyperlinked images so they don't inherit link styles

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to remove the hyperlink styles from linked images. Here's what the hyperlinks look like:
[Linked Text Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDGoS.png)

Here's what a linked image currently looks like:
[Linked Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAp3K.png)

You can see there's a green line going through the background of the image.
I have both my styles for hyperlinks and for hyperlinked images separately referenced:

```
/**** HYPERLINK STYLING ******/
a, a:visited, a:focus {
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8dc635;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #8dc635;
  color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
  transition: 0.65s;
}

a:hover {
  background: #8dc635;
}

/**** Don't style images with border / box-shadow ***/
a img {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline : none !important;
  background:transparent !important;
}

a img:hover {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline : none !important;
  background:transparent !important;
}
```

I've even tried using the !important function (as much as I'd rather not), and tried this:
    /******** No color on / in images *********************/

```
a[href$=".png"] {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
a[href$=".png"]:hover{
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Nothing has worked. . .  I'd rather not have to go in and add a class to every image on the website and I can't think how to make the selector for text hyperlinks more specific without excluding links accidentally. Ideas?

Comment: What does your markup look like? Can you provide a picture of what is occurring incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong selectors. Take the following example:

```
<a href="index.html">home</a>
<a href="contact.html">
    <img src="me.png" />
</a>
```

Now let's see how your CSS applies to them.

- The selector `a` applies to all `<a>` elements, which in this case includes both the text link and the image link.
- The selector `a img` applies to all `<img>` elements that are *inside* `<a>` elements.

Your CSS is affecting the `<img>` element and trying to remove its border, outline and shadow; however, the image itself never had any. The decorations you see come from the `<a>` element that's wrapping the `<img>` element.

Currently there is no CSS selector that selects elements which have *children* of a certain type. Here's my suggestion:

```
a:not(.image-link) {
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8dc635;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #8dc635;
    color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
    transition: 0.65s;
}

<a href="index.html">home</a>
<a href="contact.html" class="image-link">
    <img src="me.png" />
</a>
```

The `:not()` pseudoclass negates the selector inside its parentheses, so `a:not(.image-link)` will select all `<a>` elements that *do not* have the class `image-link` (in this case, the first one), and apply the decorations to those. Unfortunately, this does leave you with a bit of extra work and responsibility, because you have to make sure all your image links are given the `image-link` class.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Why doesn't this work though? Isn't this specifying the styling of the link, not the image?
a[href$=".png"]:hover{
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

Comment: Does the link itself point to a .png image, i.e. does it look like this: `<a href="avatar.png">[something here]</a>`? That's what `a[href$=".png"]` will select.

Comment: AH! Thanks. You can tell I'm self-taught. . . I appreciate your help!

Comment: No need to disparage yourself, we all start somewhere! There are some really good materials on MDN if you want to look into it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is an underline below the images? (you didn't really describe your problem...)

In that case, `border-bottom` is the wrong property, it has to be `text-decoration: none`

Comment: I was trying to turn off the hyperlink styles for linked images. Sorry for not explaining it well, but the selector I was working with wasn't text-decoration but box-shadow and border-bottom. Thank you for your help, though!